# Почему не работает wiringPi при включении модуля spi и чтении пина

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, embedded

Я делаю на Raspbery Pi программу на Qt, которая должна считывать данные с SPI, а также производить чтение пинов GPIO (14,15,17). 
Без обращения к пинам программа считывает данные SPI и корректно работает.
Как только я произвожу работу с пинами, то по всем фронтам я имею в ответ 0.
Инициализация:

```
...
void SpiApi::start() 
{
    wiringPiSetup();
    spiSetup(spiChannel);
}
...
void SpiApi::spiSetup(int spiChannel)
{
    if ((myFd = wiringPiSPISetup (spiChannel, 1000000)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open the SPI bus: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
...
```

Чтение с SPI:

```
...
int SpiApi::myAnalogRead(int spiChannel, int channelConfig, int analogChannel)
{
    if (analogChannel < 0 || analogChannel > 7)
        return -1;
    unsigned char buffer[3] = {1}; // start bit
    buffer[1] = (channelConfig + analogChannel) << 4;
    wiringPiSPIDataRW(spiChannel, buffer, 3);
    return ( (buffer[1] & 3 ) << 8 ) + buffer[2]; // get last 10 bits
}
...
```

А чтение с пинов производится методом:

```
...
int SpiApi::readPin(int port)
{
    return digitalRead(port);
}
...
```

Насчет того что у WiringPi распиновка другая, это учитывается. Тот же 15 пин у платы равен 3 у WiringPi.

Может я что-то  не учел. Подскажите... 
Система Rasbian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался сам.
Так вот. Я забыл задать порту

```
...
pinMode(pin, INPUT);
...
```

SPI после этого снова заработал.